# Question closed as belonging on Super User, but is a programming issue

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The question is:

[can gzip only store a file like zip and not compress it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42929525/6375113)

It is not a general question about software/hardware, gzip is an application but *also* a data format documented in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).

In any case, a general question does not reference a DEFLATE stream, which is documented in a separate [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt).

I have a feeling, that the people who closed my question were not familiar with this, and thus closed the question wrongly.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this, hopefully making the question less of a downvote magnet. It does seem, with the information provided here, that the question was closed at least for the wrong reason.

Comment: That said, may I suggest that you edit the information about the RFC's into the question on SO? It shows that you _did_ research and have some idea what you were asking about.

Comment: @S.L.Barth the DEFLATE reference on its own should have convinced the herd members to not close my question. They didn't know what I was asking about.

Comment: It still doesn't look like a programming question to me. Rather, it's a question about a file format asked from a user standpoint.

Comment: @JanDvorak Users knowing about DEFLATE? Give me a break.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question ended with "I need to handle this special case in my program". IMO file formats are on-topic on SO precisely because programmers need to handle them.

Comment: Maybe it would help if your question was clarified so that it could be related to a specific programming problem you have. Are you asking if a gzip file can contain other blocks than deflate? Yes, it can. Are you asking if there's an "uncompressed" compression format other than the specific part of deflate or if there's a common compressor that uses it? The latter is a recommendation question and off-topic here. The former is a bit more interesting. GZIP certainly does allow other compression methods than DEFLATE.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I missed that sentence, sorry. Otherwise I would have voted unclear instead.

Comment: @JanDvorak In practice there is nothing else than deflate in a .gzip archive. The format allows for other compression methods, but overwhelmingly there is only DEFLATE. There would be no need for .xz etc.. otherwise.

Comment: So... what _is_ the question?

Comment: My question is this: Why does your Meta post contain more details than the question itself?

Comment: Hi, another "herd" member chiming in. As noted in the RFCs you mentioned, DEFLATE blocks (still, I think, the only supported type in gzip) *can* store data as uncompressed type-0 chunks. But does gzip's implementation behave that way? Don't know, without testing it or plowing through its source. I believe I voted Too Broad for that reason, but the question is borderline on a couple of different fronts, including the majority-chosen "General Computing". You're asking, specifically, about the behavior of a program. Your question could probably be rephrased as a programming...

Comment: ... question related to the file format, and/or the handling of gzip's output (not just "I need to..."), if you were willing to consider the possibility that knowledgeable people might have voted in good faith to close the question. Or just move on, as you *did* get an answer.

Comment: Note: The close reason displayed does not indicate all users who voted to close chose that reason, only a majority did. As other people have noted, the question, in its current form, has multiple issues. We only get to specify one reason when voting to close, not all the reasons we believe apply. In addition, if the voters do not vote a consensus as to reason, the reason presented to the OP is a generic "off-topic" message without *any* specifics. Thus, in some cases, there is cause to choose the same reason as others, even when multiple reasons apply (i.e. to give some feedback to the OP).

Answer (score 16):

> I have a feeling, that the people who closed my question were not familiar with this, and thus closed the question wrongly.

Well, you might be right. OTOH, prior to posting this meta question there was no indication that *you* were familiar with it either. And therein lies the problem: if you were asking about the gzip program rather than the gzip file format and folks ignored all that and answered as though you were asking about the file format... It would just end up being a waste of their time *and* yours.

You included plenty of information *in this meta question* that would've made the focus of your question on Stack Overflow immediately obvious to folks who *are* familiar with gzip, and also made it clear to those who are not that you're talking about something they're unfamiliar with. Next time, **share your research** and put that information into your question up-front - it'll make life easier for everyone.

Comment: For the record, the quoted text are my words, not the OP's. There was originally a different qualification of the close-voters. I replaced it with a wording that I hoped to be less inflammatory.